# One function to replace different text with other in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to replace one combination of text with another. For example

```
data test;
a='raja\ram{work}italic';
if index(a,'\') then b=tranwrd(a,'\','\\');
if index(a,'{') then b=tranwrd(a,'{','\{');
if index(a,'}') then b=tranwrd(a,'}','\}');
if index(upcase(a),'ITALIC') then b=tranwrd(a,substr(a,index(upcase(a),'ITALIC'),length('ITALIC')),'\i');
run;
```

Required Result: `b=raja\\ram\{work\}\i;`

These kind of combination I wanted to replace. I'm not interested to use a macro or FCMP or if else condition.

Is there any function to do all at once? I tried to use a Perl expression that also working for one at a time `b= prxchange('s/\\/\\\\/', -1, a)`

Comment: It's very unclear what you want, but it seems to involve us doing your work for you. That's not what STack Overflow is about. Show us your code and describe in detail the problems you are having and we will help you to fix it

Comment: Actually this is a much better question than the last attempt, in my opinion.  Asking how to take code written in one form and make it more efficient is _entirely_ on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is on the right track.  You have a set of characters, right, you want to always prepend a `\` to?  So search for (one of that set of characters), which you do with `[...]`, and then add a `\` to it, using a capturing group.  That's the escape character, so you have to add two any time you want to use one (`\\` escapes itself to `\`).

```
data test;
 a='Hello\Goodbye{stuff}';
 b= prxchange('s/([\\{}])/\\$1/',-1,a);
 put b=;
run;
```

You should do the `italic` bit in a second expression (or just use `tranwrd`).  That's a totally different replacement and while theoretically possible to put in one, would make it too messy.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe. Partly, your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost identical to the other question: [Multiple search and replace within a string through regular expression in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344876/multiple-search-and-replace-within-a-string-through-regular-expression-in-sas)

Is that a coincidence?

Here is the code that worked for the other question.

```
%let text = abc\pqr{work};
data _null_;
   var=prxchange("s/\\/\\\\/",-1,"&text");
   var=prxchange("s/\{/\\\{/",-1,var);
   var=prxchange("s/\}/\\\}/",-1,var);
   put var;
run;
```

Result: `abc\\pqr\{work\};`

```
%let text = BOLD\ITALIC\ITALICBOLD\BOLDITALIC\B\I\IB\BI;
data _null_;
   var=prxchange("s/BOLD/b/",-1,"&text");
   var=prxchange("s/ITALIC/i/",-1,var);
   var=lowcase(var);
   put var;
run;
```

RESULT: `b\i\ib\bi\b\i\ib\bi`